# Why is my parallel code slower than serial?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

**Issue**

Hello everyone, I have got a program (from the net) that I intend to speed up by converting it into its parallel version with the use of `pthreads`. But surprisingly though, it runs **slower** than the serial version. Below is the program:

```
# include <stdio.h>

//fast square root algorithm
double asmSqrt(double x) 
{
  __asm__ ("fsqrt" : "+t" (x));
  return x;
}

//test if a number is prime
bool isPrime(int n)
{   
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n%2 == 0) return false;

    int sqrtn,i;
    sqrtn = asmSqrt(n);

    for (i = 3; i <= sqrtn; i+=2) if (n%i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

//number generator iterated from 0 to n
int main()
{
    n = 1000000; //maximum number
    int k,j;

    for (j = 0; j<= n; j++)
    {
        if(isPrime(j) == 1) k++;
        if(j == n) printf("Count: %d\n",k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**First attempt for parallelization**

I let the `pthread` manage the `for loop`

```
# include <stdio.h>
.
.

int main()
{
    .
    .
    //----->pthread code here<----
    for (j = 0; j<= n; j++)
    {
        if(isPrime(j) == 1) k++;
        if(j == n) printf("Count: %d\n",k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Well, it runs slower than the serial one

**Second attempt**

I divided the `for loop` into **two threads** and run them in parallel using `pthreads`

However, it still runs slower, I am intending that it may run about twice as fast or well faster. But its not!

These is my parallel code by the way:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <cmath>

# define NTHREADS 2

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int k = 0;

double asmSqrt(double x) 
{
  __asm__ ("fsqrt" : "+t" (x));
  return x;
}

struct arg_struct
{
    int initialPrime;
    int nextPrime;
};

bool isPrime(int n)
{   
    if (n <= 1) return false;

    if (n == 2) return true;

    if (n%2 == 0) return false;

    int sqrtn,i;
    sqrtn = asmSqrt(n);

    for (i = 3; i <= sqrtn; i+=2) if (n%i == 0) return false;

    return true;
}

void *parallel_launcher(void *arguments)
{
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *)arguments;

    int j = args -> initialPrime;
    int n = args -> nextPrime - 1;

    for (j = 0; j<= n; j++)
    {
        if(isPrime(j) == 1)
        {
            printf("This is prime: %d\n",j);
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
            k++;
pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
        }

        if(j == n) printf("Count: %d\n",k);
    }
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    int f = 100000000;
    int m;

    pthread_t thread_id[NTHREADS];
    struct arg_struct args;

    int rem = (f+1)%NTHREADS;
    int n = floor((f+1)/NTHREADS);

    for(int h = 0; h < NTHREADS; h++)
    {
        if(rem > 0)
        {
            m = n + 1;
            rem-= 1;
        }
        else if(rem == 0)
        {
            m = n;
        }

        args.initialPrime = args.nextPrime;
        args.nextPrime = args.initialPrime + m;

        pthread_create(&thread_id[h], NULL, &parallel_launcher, (void *)&args);
        pthread_join(thread_id[h], NULL);
    }
   // printf("Count: %d\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**
OS: Fedora 21 x86_64,
Compiler: gcc-4.4,
Processor: Intel Core i5 (2 physical core, 4 logical),
Mem: 6 Gb,
HDD: 340 Gb,

Comment: Your parallel code is still showing serial execution. In pthreads, you pass parameters as a pointer to void, therefore you can't really share a single variable unless you can guarantee that the receiving function has copied the content of the parameter before a new thread is created.

Comment: It might make the question messy so I just discuss the attempts I made for parallelization, anyway, I made numerous changes from it two weeks ago, tweaking things, but still slower than the serial one. I am attaching the parallel code I made as edit.

Comment: The `pthread_join()` function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate. If that thread has already terminated, then `pthread_join()` returns immediately. The thread specified by thread must be joinable. You need to move `pthread_join()` outside of that `for loop`. Create another `for loop` just for  `pthread_join()`. At your current code, it is still serial due to `pthread_join()` blocking until the thread exits and then it proceeds to create the next thread, hence serial.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the `pthread_join()` was in a `for loop` for generating the number of threads, so I must iterate it  from 1 to NTHREADS.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was pointing out. You will need to create all the threads first, hence the `pthread_create()` inside the original loop. You will then need to make a new loop outside of it that only has `pthread_join()` to join every single threads.

Comment: You should also make sure that `args.nextprime` is initialized before you read from it. And once you fix the problem about joining each thread as you create the thread, make sure that you pass each new thread a separate `args` struct so they aren't all trying to use the same one.

Comment: `pthread_join()` is analogous to `waitpid()`. It blocks until the thread is done. Therefore the suceeding threads are not created until the prior threads are done.

Comment: Ok, I will make changes to the code and test it. I will let you guys up to date once i got the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the range you are examining for primes up into *n* parts, where *n* is the number of threads.

The code that each thread runs becomes:

```
typedef struct start_end {
    int start;
    int end;
} start_end_t;

int find_primes_in_range(void *in) {
    start_end_t *start_end = (start_end_t *) in;

    int num_primes = 0;
    for (int j = start_end->start; j <= start_end->end; j++) {
       if (isPrime(j) == 1)
           num_primes++;
    }
    pthread_exit((void *) num_primes;
}
```

The `main` routine first starts all the threads which call `find_primes_in_range`, then calls `pthread_join` for each thread.  It sums all the values returned by `find_primes_in_range`.  This avoids locking and unlocking a shared count variable.

This will parallelize the work, but the amount of work per thread will not be equal.  This can be addressed but is more complicated.

Comment: So, in case I created two threads, both of them will have access to `num_primes`, what coding should I do so that they iterate it in the proper way?

Comment: @DominicGuana - each thread has its own separate instance of `num_primes`.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to modify the program i have, what does the `typedef struct start_end` and the `start_end_t` do? Is it different from the one I did with `struct arg_struct`?

Comment: @DominicGuana - start simple. It is easier to debug and understand a simple code. Then test this suggestion after.

Comment: @DominicGuana - the start_end structure holds the arguments to the function, just like you did with arg_struct.

Answer (score 2):

The main design flaw: you must let each thread have its own private counter variable instead of using the shared one. Otherwise they will spend far more time waiting on and handling that mutex, than they will do on the actual calculation. You are essentially forcing the threads to execute in serial.

Instead, sum everything up with a private counter variable and once a thread is done with its work, return the counter variable and sum them up in main().

Also, you should not call printf() from inside the threads. If there is a context switch in the middle of a printf call, you'll end up with crappy output such as `This is This is prime: 2`. In which case you must synchronize the printf calls between threads, which will slow the program down again. Also, the printf() calls themselves are likely 90% of the work that the thread is doing. So some sort of re-design of who does the printing might be a good idea, depending on what you want to do with the results.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

Indeed, the use of PThread speed up my code. It was my programming flaw of placing `pthread_join` right after the first `pthread_create` and the common counter I have set on arguments. After fixing this up, I tested my parallel code to determine the primality of 100 Million numbers then compared its processing time with a serial code. Below are the results.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXFyk.jpg (I could not attach the image as I don't have much reputation yet, instead, I am including a link)

I conducted three trials for each to account for the variations caused by different OS activities. We got speed up for utilizing parallel programming with `PThread`. What is surprising is a `PThread` code running in ONE thread was a bit faster than purely serial code. I could not explain this one, nevertheless using `PThreads` is well, surely worth a try.

Here is the corrected parallel version of the code (gcc-c++):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <cmath>

# define NTHREADS 4

double asmSqrt(double x) 
{
  __asm__ ("fsqrt" : "+t" (x));
  return x;
}

struct start_end_f
{
    int start;
    int end;
};

//test if a number is prime
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n%2 == 0) return false;

    int sqrtn = asmSqrt(n);
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrtn; i+=2) if (n%i == 0) return false;

    return true;
}

//executes the tests for prime in a certain range, other threads will test the next range and so on..
void *find_primes_in_range(void *in) 
{
    int k = 0;

    struct start_end_f *start_end_h = (struct start_end_f *)in;

    for (int j = start_end_h->start; j < (start_end_h->end +1); j++) 
    {
        if(isPrime(j) == 1) k++;
    }

    int *t = new int;
    *t = k;
    pthread_exit(t);
}

int main() 
{
    int f = 100000000; //maximum number to be tested for prime

    pthread_t thread_id[NTHREADS];
    struct start_end_f start_end[NTHREADS];

    int rem = (f+1)%NTHREADS;
    int n = (f+1)/NTHREADS;
    int rem_change = rem;
    int m;

    if(rem>0) m = n+1;
    else if(rem == 0) m = n;

    //distributes task 'evenly' to the number of parallel threads requested
    for(int h = 0; h < NTHREADS; h++)
    {
        if(rem_change > 0)
        {
            start_end[h].start = m*h;
            start_end[h].end = start_end[h].start+m-1;
            rem_change -= 1;
        }
        else if(rem_change<= 0)
        {
            start_end[h].start = m*(h+rem_change)-rem_change*n;
            start_end[h].end = start_end[h].start+n-1;
            rem_change -= 1;
        }
        pthread_create(&thread_id[h], NULL, find_primes_in_range, &start_end[h]);
    }   

    //retreiving returned values
    int *t;
    int c = 0;
    for(int h = 0; h < NTHREADS; h++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread_id[h], (void **)&t);
        int b = *((int *)t);
        c += b;
        b = 0;
    }

    printf("\nNumber of Primes: %d\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If one single thread is faster than pure serial, then either you have modified the code in some substantial way that make them different cases, or your method of benchmarking the code is incorrect. Because the overhead of just creating/freeing the thread should take some time.